# Allocating array of pointer in c++

Tags: c++, performance

I want to use malloc as it's memory assignment happens in `O(1)` rather than `O(n)` with the following code:

```
MyQuickInitArray(int size)
{
    A = new T[size];
}
```

When A is of type:

```
T* A
```

I thought initializing an array of pointers will take `O(1)` because pointers are primitives but i doubled checked and the code above actually goes `size` times to the constructor of `T`. If this problem can be avoided by either `malloc` or something that i'm missing than it would be great.

Comment: With malloc you then have not initialised your objects, is that really what you want?

Comment: And very often `::operator new` is built above `malloc`

Comment: You are not allocating an array of pointers, you are allocating an array of **objects** of type T

Comment: Why do you NOT want to run the constructor for your objects? What type is T?

Comment: @MatsPetersson it is a part of a class assignment

Comment: So, does your teacher say to do this? Find a new teacher!

Comment: Hmm, init. constructor on pointers is no-op. Init. constructor on POD is no-op. There is no way to get `O(n)` anyway.

Comment: @MatsPetersson yes this is what he wants. I can't find another teacher it's how things goes in this university

Comment: So, exactly what is the expected outcome from this? And you are aware that you are "learning bad stuff" right?

Comment: @MatsPetersson to imitate vector but have an initializing time of O(1)

Comment: But ALL objects (that have constructors) need to be constructed. There is no way around that in an object oriented language. Vectors have no overhead when storing pointers to objects, and as explained below `new[]` for an array of pointers doesn't have O(n) behaviour - but you will somewhere, someway or another, create the object, so eventually you get O(n) behaviour anyways - you are just pushing it ahead of you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought initializing an array of pointers will take O(1)

You are not allocating an array of pointers, you are allocating an array of **objects** of type T with your code:

```
T *A = new T[size];
```

to allocate an array of pointers you need

```
typedef T *T_Ptr;
T_Ptr *A = new T_Ptr[size];
```

I'm using a typedef so that the syntax is cleaner.

Comment: @Tom No. It's an array of objects of type T. See my edit. I've added the code that will allocate an array of pointers.

Answer (score 2):

As you correctly point out, `new T[n]` calls the constructors, whereas `malloc()` doesn't.

- If you don't want to call the constructors (why?), then clearly `new[]` isn't right for you.
- If, however, you do want to have the constructors called, then there is no way to get around the `o(n)` complexity.

If what you're looking for is an array of *pointers to `T`*, the correct syntax is as follows:

```
T** A = new T*[size];
```

This will not call `T`'s constructor.

Answer (score 0):

What about overloading the new

```
void* class_name::operator new(size_t size)
{
      cout<<"Allocating memory for object \n";
      void *p;
      p=malloc(size);
      if(p==NULL)
      cout<<"Memory allocation error\n\a";
      else
      return p;
      }
```

For array

```
void* class_name::operator new[](size_t size)
{
      cout<<"Allocating array of size "<<size<<endl;
      void *p;
      p=malloc (size);
      if(p==NULL)
      {
                 cout<<"Memory allocation error \n";
                 }
      return p;
      }
```

How it is used :

```
Class_name *objptr1,*objptr2;
objptr1=new class_name(10);
objptr2=new class_name[10];
```

Comment: I think the purpose is to avoid calling the constructor - which is nod done by calling operator new on the class.

Comment: @MatsPetersson sorry not getting you, you mean don't want to call any function at all ?

Comment: My understanding - and some others' - is that O(n) comes from calling the constructor, not allocating the memory itself [I'm fairly sure that the memory allocation is actually O(1), as it is allocated as one block - otherwise you wouldn't be sure to have a contiguous block of memory!].

Comment: The title of this Question is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

If you have allocated space for your objects you can properly initialize them using C++'s "placement new" operator; in this case `new` is not allocating memory however it will call the constructor. http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/55150/ has an example, but generally you do not want to do this, you want to allocate your objects in a non-time-critical portion of your program instead.

Comment: Again, this is O(n) for the number of objects created, since each object has to be "constructed".

Comment: @MatsPetersson of course the construction will be O(n), that can't be avoided. However allocation is not fast, and depending on what the constructor does, a single allocation could potentially take significantly more time than a (basic) constructor. This means that if done properly, performing a single allocation could reduce the actual time of this problem significantly, even though O(1)+O(n) still == O(n).

Comment: However, the allocation in new [] is done as one allocation - usually by calling malloc or some common subfunction that both standard operator new and malloc use to "get" memory. The overhead we talk about in this subject is the construction overhead, not the calling of new vs. malloc (which is still O(1) no matter how you turn it [at least in reference to how many new/malloc calls do we get, there may be characteristics of "malloc" or "new" that depend on, for example, how many free blocks there are in the system, so technically speaking, malloc/new isn't always O(1) - for another time]..